# Why is apt-get update failing inside of a docker container?

Tags: docker, osx-elcapitan, apt-get

There have been similar questions posted on this site, but my question pertains to the OSX Docker client (Version 1.11.1-beta13.1 (build: 8193) e9f58bbe60f0debccc097b7d27cad200556ec6f5), specifically.

When running `apt-get update` from a `debian:jessie` container, I obtain the following output:

```
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'httpredir.debian.org'
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'httpredir.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'httpredir.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'httpredir.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this issue on OSX?

Answer (score 1):

When we are using Virtual Machine, we depend a bit of it. And some features may not work very well. So the Docker team worked hard to eliminate this pending virtual machines in Darwin system (Mac OSX).

> Beta version -> https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/

But to try to resolve your problem, try the following commands:

1. `docker-machine restart default`
2. `docker-machine env default`
3. `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`